# Interleaving iterators

Tags: scala, iterator

I wrote the following code, expecting the last `print` method to show the elements of both iterators combined. Instead it only shows the elements of `perfectSquares`.  Can someone explain this to me?

```
object Fuge {

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    perfectSquares.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(square => print(square + " "))
    println()
    triangles.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(triangle => print(triangle + " "))
    println()
    (perfectSquares++triangles).takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(combine => print(combine + " "))

  }

  def perfectSquares : Iterator[Int] = {
    Iterator.from(1).map(x => x * x)
  }

  def triangles : Iterator[Int] = {
    Iterator.from(1).map(n => (n * (n + 1)/2))
  }

}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81    
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55 66 78 91 
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81
```

Comment: `takeWhile` *stops* when it hits something that doesn't satisfy the predicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation on `takeWhile`:

```
  /** Takes longest prefix of values produced by this iterator that satisfy a predicate.
   *
   *  @param   p  The predicate used to test elements.
   *  @return  An iterator returning the values produced by this iterator, until
   *           this iterator produces a value that does not satisfy
   *           the predicate `p`.
   *  @note    Reuse: $consumesAndProducesIterator
   */
```

What this means is that the iterator stops at that juncture. What you've created is an iterator that goes far past `100` and then, at some point, starts off at `1` again. But `takeWhile` won't go that far because it's already run into a number higher than 100. See:

```
object Fuge {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    perfectSquares.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(square => print(square + " "))
    println()
    triangles.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(triangle => print(triangle + " "))
    println()
    def interleave (a: Iterator[Int], b: Iterator[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
      if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) { Stream.empty }
      else {
        a.next() #:: b.next() #:: interleave(a, b)
      }
    }
    lazy val interleaved = interleave(perfectSquares, triangles)
    interleaved.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(combine => print(combine + " "))
  }

  def perfectSquares : Iterator[Int] = {
    Iterator.from(1).map(x => x * x)
  }

  def triangles : Iterator[Int] = {
    Iterator.from(1).map(n => (n * (n + 1)/2))
  }
}
```

Here I'm using a stream to lazily evaluate the sequence of integers. In this way we can ensure interleaving. Note that this is just interleaved, not sorted.

This yields:

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55 66 78 91 
1 1 4 3 9 6 16 10 25 15 36 21 49 28 64 36 81 45
```

To sort during a stream, you need a `BufferedIterator` and to change up the `interleave` function a bit. This is because calling `next()` advances the iterator - you can't go back. And you *also* can't know how many items you need from list `a` before you need an item from list `b`, and vice versa. But `BufferedIterator` allows you to call `head`, which is a 'peek' and does not advance the iterator. Now the code becomes:

```
object Fuge {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
    perfectSquares.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(square => print(square + " "))
    println()
    triangles.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(triangle => print(triangle + " "))
    println()
    def interleave (a: BufferedIterator[Int], b: BufferedIterator[Int]): Stream[Int] = {
      if (a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) { Stream.empty }
      else if (a.head <= b.head){
        a.next() #:: interleave(a, b)
      } else {
        b.next() #:: interleave(a, b)
      }
    }
    lazy val interleaved = interleave(perfectSquares.buffered, triangles.buffered)
    interleaved.takeWhile(_ < 100).foreach(combine => print(combine + " "))
  }

  def perfectSquares : Iterator[Int] = {
    Iterator.from(1).map(x => x * x)
  }

  def triangles : Iterator[Int] = {
    Iterator.from(1).map(n => (n * (n + 1)/2))
  }
}
```

And the output is:

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 
1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55 66 78 91 
1 1 3 4 6 9 10 15 16 21 25 28 36 36 45 49 55 64 66 78 81 91
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  How do you interleave the values in the iterators such that seperate takeWhile's are not necessary?  I want the values in the iterator to be : 1, 1, 3, 4, 6, 9 -- I guess I would sort?

Comment: If you want the output to be interleaved and sorted, then sort both the sets and merge. Something like the "merge" routine of Merge-Sort does.

Comment: @Jegan The difficulty with that approach is that you have dump the entire iterator - which could be infinite, as in this case. Or, you dump the number of elements you want (which should already be sorted) and *then* merge. But that's more inefficient than lazily evaluating a stream.

Answer (score 0):

The problems with using Streams here is that they cache all the previous data. I'd rather interleave iterators as is, without involving streams.
Something like this:

```
class InterleavingIterator[X, X1 <: X, X2 <: X](
    iterator1: Iterator[X1],
    iterator2: Iterator[X2]) extends Iterator[X] {
  private var i2: (Iterator[X], Iterator[X]) = (iterator1, iterator2)

  def hasNext: Boolean = iterator1.hasNext || iterator2.hasNext

  def next: X = {
    i2 = i2.swap
    if (i2._1.hasNext) i2._1.next else i2._2.next
  }
}
```

Comment: Not completely accurate. A `Stream` will "cache" (memoize) only if something hangs on to the head. If the `Stream` is declared as a `def`, and nothing hangs on to the head, then every element is up for GC after it's used.